# Build error trying to get fb sdk working

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

My goal: create a page that logs in via facebook

What I've done so far: followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

The problem that I need help with: when I add

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

to the dependencies in app | Gradle Scripts | build.gradle (Module: app)

it fails to build and presents the error message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

The two other compiles in the dependencies by default are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Hovering over the top statement presents the message:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.

Android studio version is 2.3.3 and facebook SDK is 4.24.0
Does anyone know why these errors are occurring and/or how to fix them? Thanks

Comment: I have same issue. if change `26.+` to `25.3.1` occur this error
`Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

add `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'` if you don't use it.

Comment: I gave this a try but unfortunately it still causes the same error.

Comment: 100% same? I add `com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1` too.

Comment: @susemi99 +1 adding custom tabs support dependency helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by adding CustomTabs dependency :

> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.+'

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46212995/5273427

For your convinience here's the code (credits to [ישו אוהב אותך](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758255/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9A)):

```
// Facebook SDK Dependencies, need to be excluded.
// compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
// compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
// compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
// compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'

compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```