# android:facebook-login:4.29.0, exclude android.support to use it with SDK 26

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin

I am using SDK 26 (support 26.1.0). I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47360826/455796 and did the following,

```
def support_version = '26.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:${support_version}"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0'{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
}
```

but it caused,

Error: Could not find method com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0() for arguments [build_b8xyg6u02oo8u0yoih8oe3tvs$_run_closure2$_closure6@b26df6f] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Can I solve this, or would I have to use an old version of the Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     //others
}
```

or

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.29.0', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
     //others
}
```